# GEE: Number of pixels requested from Image.load exceeds the maximum allowed (2^31). (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have [some code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/59fe0085fa85e18c147971c32b055ada) that works when the final step is Map.addLayer() (i.e., no errors and it displays a value) but when I try to export the image, I get the following error:

> Error: Number of pixels requested from Image.clip exceeds the maximum
> allowed (2^31). (Error code: 3)

if I remove the .clip() step, I get this error:

> Error: Image.reduceRegions: Number of pixels requested from Image.load
> exceeds the maximum allowed (2^31). (Error code: 3)

I tried reducing the region to a very small polygon, but got the same errors.

Basically, I am trying to aggregate the values in this raster to a MODIS pixel, which I do in two steps:

```
var WV15 = t2015c.select('b1')
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
      maxPixels: 65536
    })
    .reproject(t2015c.projection(), null, 50)
       .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
      maxPixels: 65536
    })    .reproject("SR-ORG:6974", null, modisscale)    .rename('Taymir_WV_15').toDouble()
```

I also tried increasing shardSize to 20,000, as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298520/google-earth-engine-error-number-of-pixels-requested-from-image-load-exceeds-th), but that did not fix the errors.

Comment: To be sure , have you verified that GEE understands the coordinate system "SR-ORG:6974" right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in one go; you need to export the intermediate result of the first reduceResolution.